# Operation could destabilize the runtime error when invoke ToString from int using Emit

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

This code works

```
var toString = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { });

var dm = new DynamicMethod("MyToString", typeof(string), new Type[] { typeof(string) });

var il = dm.GetILGenerator();

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, toString);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

Delegate d = dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, string>));

var r = d.DynamicInvoke("10");
```

This code throws an exception (System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.)

```
var toString = typeof(int).GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { });

var dm = new DynamicMethod("MyToString", typeof(string), new Type[] { typeof(int) });

var il = dm.GetILGenerator();

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, toString);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

Delegate d = dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, string>));

var r = d.DynamicInvoke(10);
```

why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `Ldarg_0`, you load the value of argument 0. For invoking instance methods on a value type `T`, the implicit `this` parameter doesn't have type `T`, it has type `ref T`, so you need to load not the value, but a reference to argument 0. The `Ldarga` instruction will do that for you. That's the immediate problem.

A less serious problem, though one that goes undetected for me and I'm not 100% sure if it's strictly required, is that you should be the `Call` instruction for instance methods on value types, or in some specific cases, the `Constrained` prefix before the `Callvirt` instruction.

In general, don't guess what CIL instructions you need. Write your intended code once in C#, compile it, and disassemble the result. That tells you the exact instructions that you can easily see working.

Comment: The Ldarga command dont work either, I'll try to decompile to see how it works

Comment: `Ldarga`+`Call` is what Roslyn generates too. If that doesn't work for you, then you're doing something wrong, but I wouldn't know what. For a quick online decompilation check, try `public static class C { public static string F(int i) => i.ToString(); }` on http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried again with the Ldarga  and now works, I don't know what I was doing wrong yesterday